# SQL LIKE from multiple table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a search bar that could list the product name and product owner.

> Table ITEM consist of pID (FK from PROFILE), itemName, and itemDate
>
> Table PROFILE consist of pID, firstName, and lastName

Initially, the `'%$Keurig%'` supposed to be `'%$searchtag%'` (the value passed from search bar).

However since it didn't show anything, I decided to use `'%$Keurig%'` to find out what happened.

Turns out, it didn't show anything as well.

Here's what I wrote:

```
SELECT I.itemName,P.firstName,P.lastName
      FROM `ITEM` I, `PROFILE` P
      WHERE I.pID=P.pID AND I.itemName LIKE '%$Keurig%'
```

It supposed to print a user name John because he is the only one that owns Keurig.

Anybody knows what I did wrong? Thank you.

Comment: why added `$` in '%$Keurig%'

Comment: Try `LIKE '%Keurig%'` instead. MySQL like works as substring search.

Comment: That makes sense. However, why when I changed it back to `'%$searchtag%'` it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `$` from `'%$Keurig%'`. Try this

```
SELECT I.itemName,P.firstName,P.lastName
  FROM `ITEM` I, `PROFILE` P
  WHERE I.pID=P.pID AND I.itemName LIKE '%Keurig%'
```

With `$searchtag` try somthing like this

```
$sql = "SELECT I.itemName,P.firstName,P.lastName
  FROM `ITEM` I, `PROFILE` P
  WHERE I.pID=P.pID AND I.itemName LIKE '%".$searchtag."%'";
```

Comment: But why when I changed back into `'%$searchtag%'`, it doesn't work?

Comment: You need to concat your searchtag in query

Comment: Yes, you are right. Furthermore, I have to remove all the single quotation in order to make it work. I have to change from `'I.itemName'` into `I.itemName`

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will checklist your post :)

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer helped you please mark as right answer so others can take help from it.

Comment: I just did. It didn't allow me earlier, it asked to wait for 2 minutes.